# Recording audio and video in Arch Linux

Tags: video, arch-linux, audio-recording

I've been looking around, Google-ing and stuff and I haven't been able to find anything that I like.

I need something similar to Screencast for the Mac, but it doesn't need to have the editor part as well, that I can handle with other software.

What I need is something that can record the input from a headset, and the output of the screen at 30FPS constant. I just need it to output the sound in one file, and the video in another, the formats don't matter as long as they're not low quality, since they're gonna be re-encoded anyway.

If I need to launch two apps for this, I don't mind but it's not ideal.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sugestion is: [RecordMyDesktop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RecordMyDesktop). Should meet your needs.

*RecordMyDesktop* is screencasting software for X. It can record audio through [ALSA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture), OSS or the JACK audio server. It is the only screencasting software able capture through jack and thus is important for pro-audio video tutorials.

Comment: I see, I'll check that out then. If it works for my needs I'll approve your answer. :)

Comment: Well it seems it'll work for my needs, screen recording wise. However I can't figure out how to make it record audio from the computer, like record the sound of a video that's on YouTube for example (for test purposes). I am using the ALSA drivers (`jack_control ds alsa`). Any tips? It records video correctly BTW (not at a great quality though).

Comment: Look: http://www.linuxplanet.org/blogs/?cat=726

Comment: Well after a lot of stuff I wasn't able to figure it out. In any case recording internal audio is not all that important, what matters is the headset's audio. And the video. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK after tinkering more with it, this time with the GTK GUI, it works great! Now comes another question, but I'll post it in a separate question.